# Connecting with putty on windows to a server and then to a opensuse computer. Cannot connect o X server localhost:11.0

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, putty, opensuse

i have read a lot of posts about this but none have solved my problem, any help is much appreciated.

I'm trying to ssh from my windows machine to a linux cluster and from there to a linux pc running open suse to which my home directory is mounted (meaning i dont have a home in the cluster).

I do both connections with ssh -vv -Y because the cluster and the pc to which i log in only have the option ForwardX11Trusted yes.

I have installed Xming and have run Xlaunch prior to this in my windows machine.

The second ssh, the one to the pc that mounts my home, gives this warning "Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding."

when running a program i get the following error "cannot connect to X server localhost:11.0"

i have also tried using xauth list and xauth add but still get the same error